# Code First EF: Enum Id not being added to database during database generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I just changed my datamodel, I want to have some default items in data table when the database is generated by EF for the first time. Previously, I did that from seed method. But Now I found that it would be more useful and the amount of codes I have to write would be less If I use enum (with default values).

This is my current model after adding `enum`

```
public partial class License
{     
    public int LicenseId { get; set; }
    public LicenseTypes Licensetype { get; set; }
}

public enum LicenseTypes
{
    Trial = 0,
    Paid = 1
}
```

and this is my `DbContext` class

```
public partial class InfoBridgeSmartDatePickerDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public InfoBridgeSmartDatePickerDbContext():base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<License> Licenses { get; set; }

}
```

when I run the application, the database is generated but the table `Licenses` doesn't contain the `values` or `Id` of `enum`. Shouldn't it be holding the `values` or `Id` of enum?

The **EF version** I'm using is: `6.0.2`

Comment: There should indeed be a `Licensetype int not null` column in table `License`; I don't see a problem with the code you have posted

Comment: But will the table also generate two rows, with Id as 0,1 and LicenseType as Trial and Paid, or do I have to add it to the table during seed method?

Comment: Currently I don't know what to expect in the table, just table with empty colums (LicenseId and LicenseType) or columns with some values

Comment: May be I have completely different thing in my head of how this thing works.

Comment: No, `License` in your code is an entity and expects a `LicenseTypes` value as one of its fields with a separate `LicenseId` field.  You could use `LicenseTypes` as the PK of an entity, but you would still need to manually add an instance of the entity for each enum value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there'll be no enumeration values in database. EF manages only the conversion from primitive to enumeration, there's no constraint at database level.

Comment: I'm new to this enum and code first, so lets say If i have to assign LicenseId to user then how would I do that, since my data table in database has no idea about what Licenses are there

Comment: But for me it doesn't even hold the Id, it is completely blank, I think it should at least have the Id value

Comment: @Biplov13 You should fill the table with the data you need, EF can't do that for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
public partial class License
{     
    public int LicenseId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public LicenseTypes Licensetype { get; set;{ _default = value; } }
}
```

I have used is for single value, for object you check once hope..it do the trick